# Row binding of arrays loaded from JSON sources in R

Tags: r, json

I feel this must be an easy issue, but my search fu is failing me, so your assistance is very welcome, and apologies if it is indeed answered elsewhere.

I'm working with JSON data from a REST API (specifically GitHub data for pull requests) which contains nested arrays (in this case, the comments on the PRs, which then nest other things, like the data for the comment author). I use `JSONlite::fromJSON` to parse this, and I get a dataframe with nested sets of lists and data.frames. Here's a cut-down example of a single row (PR):

```
jsn = '[
         {
           "pr":123,
            "comment_total":2,
            "comments":[
              {
                "user":{"name":"Me Myself","username":"me"},
                "body":"comment 1"
              },
              {
                "user":{"name":"Me Myself","username":"me"},
                "body":"comment 2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]'
```

This represents a single pull request, which has two comments on it. If I load this with JSONLite, I get 1 row as expected:

```
> df = jsonlite::fromJSON(jsn)
> str(df)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ pr           : int 123
 $ comment_total: int 2
 $ comments     :List of 1
  ..$ :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ user:'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ name    : chr  "Me Myself" "Me Myself"
  .. .. ..$ username: chr  "me" "me"
  .. ..$ body: chr  "comment 1" "comment 2"
```

I'd like to unwrap the first level of this `comments` column, so that I get one row per PR comment, but I'm struggling to do so. What I'm aiming for is something like:

```
     pr  comment_total comments.user comments.body
1   123              2  <data.frame>     comment 1
2   123              2  <data.frame>     comment 2
```

I thought `tidyr::unnest()` would deal with this, but it doesn't seem to like the nested data.frames:

```
> unnest(df)
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Argument 1 can't be a list containing data frames
```

I also looked at `purrr::map_dfr` which outputs rows, but I can't seem to get that right either - I'm using it to access the data.frame directly, but it's still unhappy:

```
> map_dfr(df,.id="comments", `[[`,1)
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Argument 3 can't be a list containing data frames
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see it - someone enlighten me? Thanks!

EDIT: The code I'm using to get the data from GitHub looks like below - if there are better ways to query this, I'm interested.

```
library(httr)

base_url   = 'https://api.github.com/repos/ansible/ansible'

# `pr` comes from a loop, e.g. pr = 38508
issue_url  = paste0(base_url,'/issues/',pr,'/comments')

# api_user and api_key are my GitHub credentials    
i_resp <- GET(issue_url, authenticate(api_user,api_key))

issue_comments = as.tibble(
                   jsonlite::fromJSON(
                     content(i_resp,as="text"),
                       flatten = TRUE
                     )
                   )
```

Comment: There are quite a few GitHub API packages out there. Is this response coming from those or are you manually querying the API (or have others done the query and dumped a ton of JSON on you)?

Comment: I'm getting the data myself via the GitHub API and the `httr` package. I'll update the question with the code I'm using for that.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Added the code. A GitHub specific package would be one solution in this case - however I've encountered this nesting issue in other APIs (such as Meetup) so learning how to handle this properly would be lovely.

Comment: I've just realised that while I use `httr` for *some* of my data collection, the rest comes from an Elastic db that I have no control over the schema for. I can post a separate question for that, if that's the right thing to do...

Comment: It may help others who are in similar conditions (i.e. I think there are likely more than a few R folks who currently or in the future may have to deal with elasticsearch raw output) to file a new q.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to tell `jsonlite` to not be as helpful as it usually is and then work the unwinding on your own (much like XML processing, heavily nested output from custom API endpoints tend to need some domain/API knowledge to get the data into rectangles):

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(
  txt = jsn, 
  simplifyVector = FALSE, 
  simplifyDataFrame = FALSE, 
  flatten = FALSE
) %>% 
  map_df(~{ # in case there is more than one
    dplyr::as_data_frame(.x) %>% 
      mutate(
        body = map_chr(comments, ~.x$body),
        username = map_chr(comments, ~.x$user$name),
        name = map_chr(comments, ~.x$user$name)
      ) %>% 
      select(-comments)

  })
## # A tibble: 2 x 5
##      pr comment_total body      username  name     
##   <int>         <int> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
## 1   123             2 comment 1 Me Myself Me Myself
## 2   123             2 comment 2 Me Myself Me Myself
```

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks! I find your comment about domain knowledge interesting - you're saying there's basically no way to flatten *any* given nested JSON response? (I'm fine with that, I'd just assumed there *Is* a way, and I wasn't seeing it)

Comment: Also, I'm unclear on what ~{ ... } does as a formula, can you explain that a little? I've seen "~ x" as a shorthand for "function(x) x" but not with the curly braces.